# Samsung Duos Mac address keeps changing

Tags: samsung

I have a Samsung Duos GT-I9082 (Android 4.2.2).

Every time the screen turns off or is locked, the WiFi gets turned off. Then on the MAC address changes so I cannot connect to the WiFi due to MAC filtering.

Could you please help me figure this out? Thanks.

Comment: The MAC address changes by itself? I've never seen that before - are you sure that its the MAC and not the IP, and is there anything running on wake / login to change the MAC ? I'm thinking incredibly short DHCP lease time - but that wouldnt affect the MAC, only the IP.

Comment: @FreudianSlip yes I'm sure it's the MAC address. That's why I posted this question. I'm astonished as well.

Answer (score 0):

The smartphone's wifi turned out to be spoofed.

Comment: With a random MAC address? Why did you do that?

Comment: @JasonC yes almost. Only the last few numbers are changing.

Comment: Unless you specifically installed some app or mod to change the MAC address, that almost sounds more like a bug in a custom kernel mod. Did you root the device?

Comment: @JasonC no I personally did nothing. I've also been told that the device is made in Korea and that the Wi-Fi used is a cheap one that is spoofed.